# How can i make this working. I tried giving sudo permissoins

Tags: javascript, linux, react-native, expo

**
I'm currently using linux. and tried with starting the app with sudo permission and it didn't work.
**
I just installed expo-cli and created new project. When I start the app. It shows

Error message

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/haste-map-metro-4-36677ec4ffe69a9c48969ce0c6048f0e-05d9595d1f7d32f85d732f06fd3b25e9'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:465:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1416:35)
    at Object.writeFileSync (/home/muthu/workspace/bootcamp/native/first/node_modules/jest-serializer/build/index.js:196:21)
    at HasteMap._persist (/home/muthu/workspace/bootcamp/native/first/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:944:31)
    at /home/muthu/workspace/bootcamp/native/first/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:497:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/muthu/workspace/bootcamp/native/first/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:193:24)
    at _next (/home/muthu/workspace/bootcamp/native/first/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:213:9) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/tmp/haste-map-metro-4-36677ec4ffe69a9c48969ce0c6048f0e-05d9595d1f7d32f85d732f06fd3b25e9'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Changing the permission on your tmp folder will resolve that, try with:

```
chmod -R 0777 /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /tmp
sudo chmod 700 /tmp/root-states
```

Answer (score -1):

An import process fails because the system cannot find the path specified, modify permission settings for the temporary directory that the operating system uses during the import process.

For the ubuntu os:

Run:

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp
sudo chmod a+rwx /tmp
```

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Be cautious this is a security hazard. /tmp files should not only be accessible by other users. It should have either sticky or capabilities set to protect the files.

Comment: Security hazard. /tmp should be protected. Answer puts the casual reader at risk.