# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fs.js

Tags: react-native, expo, fs

I am working in React Native using expo-cli.

All I did till now is

```
expo init myapp
```

And after adding a text to my app.js file, I tried to do

```
npm start
```

which gave me this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fs.js
```

I have not used anything related to fs.js and as far as I can see from the errors page, the error is in

```
.../node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
```

And other file stack system is referring it to metro.
I am using VS code and Linux Mint for development. My expo version is: 4.3.0

The result of expo diagnostics

```
Expo CLI 4.3.0 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.4 Linux Mint 20.1 (Ulyssa)
      Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.19.0 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~40.0.0 => 40.0.1 
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2 
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 4.3.0
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Comment: try removing node_modules and reinstalling. also, run `expo diagnostics` in your project and share the result here

Comment: Reinstalling all node_modules does not work. The result of expo diagnostics is above.

Comment: can you try running `EXPO_DEBUG=1 expo start`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be running `expo start` instead of `npm start`?

Answer (score 1):

try to start as an administrator with `sudo yarn start`

Comment: Highly recommend against running yarn as root, in vast majority of cases should not be necessary

Comment: yes I agree, but in same case when you install your package as root or your package manager 'yarn or npm' not installed globally, you need to start as root.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it here but I'm not sure what caused this problem.
first i restarted the computer, when i did this another error similar to this one appeared
[How can i make this working. I tried giving sudo permissoins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454554/how-can-i-make-this-working-i-tried-giving-sudo-permissoins)

so I ran

```
chmod -R 0777 / tmp
```

But it didn't work. so I deleted the node module and ran

```
sudo yarn install
yarn start --reset-cache
```

And the problem was solved